# Border-bottom doers not come as underline in Chrome and Firefox; works in IE

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have HTML code as given in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/FRBqJ/. In internet explorer it works fine - the header text comes with an underline. But in Firefox and Chrome the line is not coming as underline.

1. What is the reason for this incorrect behavior?
2. How can we correct it (using CSS) ?

Firefox

[image]

IE

[image]

HTML

```
    <div id="searchContainer" class="searchContainer">
                        <div id="searchHeader" class="searchHeader">
                            <span id="detailContentPlaceholder_lblSearchHeading" class="searchContentHeadingText">
                                Business Testing Act</span>
                            <img alt="Expand" src="Images/PlusIcon.GIF" class="expandSearchIcon" />
                            <img alt="Collapse" src="Images/MinusIcon.GIF" class="collapseSearchIcon" />
                        </div>
   </div>
```

CSS

```
.searchHeader
{
width:100%; 
border-bottom:2px solid #fcda55;
padding:0 0 2px 0;
margin:0 0 0 0px;
font:bold 13pt Arial;
line-height:10pt;
color:#00A6B5;
}
```

REFERENCE:

1. [CSS text-underline rendering difference between FF/IE and Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8865027/css-text-underline-rendering-difference-between-ff-ie-and-chrome)

[image: profile for Lijo at Stack Overflow, Q&A for professional and enthusiast programmers]

Comment: First, IE is the one who misbehaves, not FF and Chrome.  Second, you don't actually have the border applied to the HEADER, you have it applied to a DIV which contains a floated element.  Un-float the span inside the div, and it works properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using `float`, you should also add`overflow: auto;` to the parent element so that it accounts for the floated element:

```
.searchHeader
{
    width:100%; 
    border-bottom:2px solid #fcda55;
    padding:0 0 2px 0;
    margin:0 0 0 0px;
    font:bold 13pt Arial;
    line-height:10pt;
    color:#00A6B5;
    overflow: auto;  /* Right here */
}
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/FRBqJ/1/**